# Copied Emails From HTML Not Working In Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, email

Hello there Stackoverflow. I have a question regarding HTML formatting. I have bootstrap modal where I dynamically modify it's body content using jQuery using the `append()` function. Here's the code:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <pre id="emails"></pre>
</div>

var s = email.trim();
$('#emailsModal').find('.modal-body').find('#emails').append("<p>"+s+"</pre>");
```

And here's the ouput:

[image]

This list is designed so a user may copy the list and paste it into whatever email program they desire. This worked fine on most, such as gmail and micrsoft outlook. The problem is occurs when I attempt to copy this list of emails into the program Thunderbird.

For some reason when I copy the emails the clipboard contains a line break and Thunderbird is considering it a blank email. Therefore the output looks something like this:

`email1@example.com,,email2@example.com,,email3@example.com ...`

These double commas are obviously not proper syntax and therefore the email will not send.

Can anybody help me out with this problem? I would like each email output on a new line in the modal but I also need the emails to be able to be copy and pasted into a newly composed email without issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `"<br/>"+s` in your append call instead of `"<p>"+s+"</pre>"`?  Then you will only be appending a line break and not a new paragraph. So there will only be one line break between each email  - currently it appears that you have two.  Also, you're opening one tag and closing a different tag in every appending.  `<p> != <pre>`

Comment: My first instinct was to modify the data stored when you copy it to the clipboard, however from the browser you don't have access to the clipboard for security reasons..

Comment: @Bardicer Worked beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: I'll convert the comment into an answer then.  I wasn't completely positive it would work, but it seemed the most logical choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"<br/>"+s` in your append call instead of `"<p>"+s+"</pre>"`? Then you will only be appending a line break and not a new paragraph.